# How to get Bottom navigation buttons visibility status in android 10 or greater

Tags: android, android-layout

I am implementing my app in full screen, and I am getting the problem when system UI have bottom navigation buttons. The bottom navigation buttons are covering the area. How do I know that full screen display is enable or not? (i.e. in Latest Xiomi mobiles we can show/hide bottom navigation buttons)

Comment: Mate have you tried checking the screen resolutions first?

Comment: No. For time being I did that I find the height of the bottom navigation buttons and give the bottom margin programmatically. But it always give me height of bottom navigation button in android 10 or higher, If the bottom navigation is showing or not

Comment: Yes man I am also facing the same issue.